# Django generic foreign key reverse filter

Tags: django, generic-foreign-key

I have a model called "Comments" which uses a generic foreign key:

```
class CommentManager(models.Manager):

    def for_model(self, model):
        """
        QuerySet for all comments for a particular model (either an instance or
        a class).
        """
        ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(model)
        qs = self.get_query_set().filter(content_type=ct)
        if isinstance(model, models.Model):
            qs = qs.filter(object_pk=force_text(model._get_pk_val()))
        return qs


class Comment(models.Model):
    """
    A user comment about some object.
    """
    status = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_status = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    comment = models.TextField()

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        verbose_name=_('content type'),
        related_name="content_type_set_for_%(class)s")
    object_pk = models.TextField(_('object ID'))
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey(ct_field="content_type",
                                               fk_field="object_pk")
```

One of the things you can put comments on are `Tickets`:

```
class Ticket(CommonModel):
    type = models.ForeignKey(TicketType)
    priority = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    status = models.ForeignKey(TicketStatus)
    access_serial_number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, related_name='child')
    submitted = models.DateTimeField()
```

I do a lot of filtering of `Tickets` - in the past all I did with Comments on Tickets is that when I displayed a `Ticket`, I used `Comments.objects.for_model(ticket)` to find all the Comments for it. But now what I want to do is find `Tickets` that have a specific text in the comment. There is no `comment_set` or equivalent with `GenericForeignKey`.

This is what I've come up with, but it's pretty horrible:

```
comment_ticket_ids = [int(c.object_pk) for c in Comment.objects.for_model(Ticket).filter(comment__icontains='error')]
tickets = Ticket.filter(status=open_status, id__in=comment_ticket_ids)
```

There must be a better way.

Comment: How are you relating `Comments` to `Tickets`? I've read through your question several times but I don't see the relationship in your code example.

Comment: I add comments to tickets using the `GenericForeignKey` content_object, as in `comment = Comment(content_object=my_ticket, status="Ticket Created", comment="So and so created this ticket for grins").save()`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could add something using `.extra()` to help. Instead of

```
comment_ticket_ids = [int(c.object_pk) for c in Comment.objects.for_model(Ticket).filter(comment__icontains='error')]
tickets = Ticket.filter(status=open_status, id__in=comment_ticket_ids)
```

You could attach the field `id_wanted`:

```
extra_select = {
 'id_wanted': 'CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tickets WHERE comments something) > 0 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END'
}
```

Then filter for tickets with the extra select:

```
tickets = Tickets.objects.filter(ticket__status=open_status, id_wanted__isnull=False).extra(extra_select)
```

---

It's not fully clear to me why you can't have a FKey relationship between these two models.

Comment: 1. We use a GenericForeignKey because you can attach Comments to things other than Tickets.

Comment: 2. I'm not clear how your suggestion works - it appears to be attaching a `id_wanted` to Comment and then expecting it to be there in a query that doesn't involve Comment?

Comment: I revised my answer - will delete if un-useful. I'm trying to translate a pattern I used, where I also had a content type relationship (allowing comments on many different objects) and used a `.extra()` clause in our queryset